# Language & translation

Tags: translation

I have purchased the SoCute WP theme and as default it's in English. I want it to be in Swedish, so I have made updates to the wp-config.php file:

```
define('WPLANG', ’sv_SE’);
```

and I have uploaded mo and po files to the languages folder. 
I think I have tried everything but nothing seems to do the trick. If someone knows more about this, I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please try the [Debug Translations plugin](http://marketpress.com/product/debug-translations/).

Comment: `define('WPLANG', ’sv_SE’);` should be `define('WPLANG', 'sv_SE');`

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate your input and help. I just updated the wp-config accordingly but the site is still in english? I have uploaded the mo and po files to both /language and to the theme-language, could this be the cause? Sorry but I'm kind of a WP-newbie :)

Comment: How did you name your files

Comment: sv_SE.po  and  sv_SE.mo  and wp-config.php  Thanks!

Comment: Did you actually translate some strings to Swedish. This should work, you've named your files correctly. How did you create your po and mo files

Comment: Did you actually try the plugin that @toscho recommended.

Comment: I used Poedit, I followed the theme documentation and renamed the default.po file, then edited a few strings in Poedit and uploaded the file via FTP but it just won't show in Swedish. I'll download the plugin @toscho recommended.

Comment: Ok, just downloaded the plugin: please see below for some examples:

Locale: en_US

Domain:    yit
File:      /storage/content/10/196910/hunkydog.se/public_html/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/languages/yit-en_US.mo (not found)
Called in: /storage/content/10/196910/hunkydog.se/public_html/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/init.php line 44 load_plugin_textdomain

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but: did you install the Swedish version of WordPress (containing the Swedish language files for the WordPress core)?

Comment: Hi! No silly question at all @Yosi Mor, big thank you for this reminder. I'll check with the agency that installed it. Thank you!